# Is there a known way to force your images to be displayed when sending newsletters?

Tags: image, email, gmail, spam, newsletter

I've got this email today with a big image displayed on it and with no option to hide the images on that email: http://clip2net.com/s/1xo7u

By default Gmail does not display images from unknown senders, and always display options to display or hide the images from the email. Who did these guys bypassed Gmail's image filter?

Is there a known way to force your images to be displayed when sending newsletters?

Before you close my question as off-topic, please let me argue that this is a programming related issue because automated newsletters are a very common requirement in web programming projects, and myths of people (spammers) being able to force images to display are to be confronted frequently by software developers.

Comment: If there was a way to force images to be displayed in emails, don't you think spammers would be abusing that already? What you want is not possible, and almost certainly will NEVER be possible.

Comment: The problem is that I have been asked this lots of times by several clients. I too believe this is not possible, but I have no proof. In fact I´ve received myself emails where images are displayed by default in gmail and I don´t know why. So, what I need is some proof or references to credible sources stating something clear about this. And if there is a hacker out there who have tested this, his opinion would really be relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that at present (this may change) that as long as the image is embedded into the mime message and is marked as inline Google Mail will display in the message. This may or may not apply to different mail clients.

We do this when we send out status emails to include the icons that we display within a table in the email content. If the images are not referenced by the message content then the images appear as attachments. However, if the images are referenced then they're not listed as attachments and are displayed inline.

Inline images don't pose a threat from spammers because they're not making a call to an external server and are therefore not trackable. You can do this in your app by setting the attachment mime headers (content disposition and content-ID) such as:

```
Content-Disposition: inline;
  filename=image.png
Content-ID: <4f22bc6ab05be_17a1dcc610ac@b456a124-73ac-499f-932e-7f76089dbbb4.mail>
```

and then reference it using:

```
<img src="cid:4f22bc6ab05be_17a1dcc610ac@b456a124-73ac-499f-932e-7f76089dbbb4.mail" />
```

Comment: ¿Have anyone tested this in more than a single email client?

Comment: For context: There's nothing troubling about showing an image in an email, but there are privacy issues with *fetching* an image to show in an email: specifically, it allows the sender to track whether an email has been opened. Newsletters use this for analytics, which is fine, but spammers use this to determine which addresses are active. The point of this feature is to keep spammers from flagging your address as a target. Attached images don't let spammers do that, so Gmail lets them be.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, you can never force the client to do so. Since those are security measures the developers of the e-mail applications will not allows you to override the usersettings.

Answer (score 2):

Make the image into ascii art :-)